# Javascript: Delete an object with a array within a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angularjs, object

Dear Stackoverflow friends,

I have a question, i'm busy with a NodeJS - Angular application.
To save and delete parts of a form i use an object:

```
$scope.entries = {
  events:{
    save:{},
    del:[],
    save_count:0},

  actions:{
    save:{},
    del:[],
    save_count:0},

  packages:{
    save:{},
    del:[],
    save_count:0}
}
```

Now for example i have an object like this (saved in packages)

```
save:{
  1398944325398:{
   action: 6461,
   budget: 1000,
   events: [123, 1242],
   id: 209
   name: "Jeffrey"},
 1398949842824:{
   action: 6441,
   budget: 1020,
   events: [153, 12422],
   id: 21
   name: "Jeffrey2"}
}
```

So when i want to delete the key: 1398944325398
I have the following code:

```
delete $scope.entries.package.save['1398944325398'];
```

But when i send this object $scope.entries to my Node server i get this:

```
packages:{
 del: Array[0],
 save:{
  1398944325398:{
   events: Array[0]
  },
  1398949842824:{
   action: 6441,
   budget: 1020,
   events: [153, 12422],
   id: 21
   name: "Jeffrey2"}
 },
 save_count: 0
}
```

Why won't javascript delete my object if there is an array in that object?
Setting the array to 'null'
Won't solve the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eBbkP/

This is your scenario right? Seems to do whats expected in the browser

Comment: why you put the code with syntax errors or this is the real example?

Comment: Like @AndreyBorisko asked, is this a real example? You're trying to delete from "package" but the property is called "packages"?

Comment: This is the real problem, if i change the property from a object to a string like so:
$scope.entries.package.save['1398944325398'] = "test";

I'll get an Angular error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn:%20function%20()%7Bvar%20a%3Dm(e)%3Bp(a,H%5Bc%5D)%7C%7C(p(a,l)%3Fn(e,a%3DH%5Bc%5D):H%5Bc%5D%3Da)%3Breturn%20l%3Da%7D%3B%20newVal

Seems like i have a problem with my $watch

Comment: @Marco it seems this is a angular problem and not a real javascript problem

Comment: @JeffreyBouva are you calling it `$scope.entries.packages` or `$scope.entries.package`? (the missing 's' at the end). this makes a big difference

Comment: @japrescott thanks for the heads up. I found the problem in a module of angular. NgTagsInput. if the ng-model is undefined it will make a new array. This is why i couldn't delete the object! Thanks guys!